# How to mock a script that is dot sourced?

Tags: powershell, mocking, pester

We're trying to figure out how to `mock` a dot sourced script in `Pester`.

**Script1.ps1**

```
$Import = @('Script 1 data')

. 'C:\Script2.ps1' -JobName 'Script 2 data'

$Import
```

**Script2.ps1**

```
Param (
    [String]$JobName
)

$Import += $JobName
```

**Output**

```
Script 1 data
Script 2 data
```

In the example above `Script2.ps1` is already tested in a separate `Pester` test file (`Script2.Tests.ps1`). For the testing of `Script1.ps1` we only have a need to asses if the other script is called or not.

In `Script1.ps1` we explicitly use dot sourcing to make sure that the changed/updated variables come back in the current scope.

An approach would be to use a `Function` with the sole purpose of calling `Script2.ps1` that can then be easily mocked. However, in that case the variable modifications are stuck in the function scope.

What is the best way to assess if the script has been called and still make sure the variables come back in the current scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have the `Return` keyword that you can use to send data across scopes in your case. You can use `Return` inside the function you talked about or `Script2.ps1` itself. You do not need to modify your variable in another script. Instead, pass it the value, modify it locally in `Script2`, `Return` it to `Script1` where you grab the modified value.

**Script1**

```
$Import = @('Script 1 data')

$ModValue = . 'C:\Script2.ps1' -JobName 'Script 2 data'

$Import += $ModValue
$Import
```

**Script2**

```
Param (
    [String]$JobName
)
#do what you need to do here
$modifiedvalue = $JobName #For the sake of demo i am doing this.

Return $modifiedvalue #Where $modifiedvalue is what you want to send back to script1
```

**Output**

```
Script 1 data
Script 2 data
```

You can add errorhandling in script2 if you expect it and return error messages to Script1 as well. Checking the value of `$ModValue` in that case can give you better control on understanding what happens in script2.

```
Param (
    [String]$JobName
)

try
{
    #do what you need to do here
    $modifiedvalue = $JobName #For the sake of demo

    Return $modifiedvalue #Where $modifiedvalue is what you want to send back to script1
}
catch
{
    Return $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: That is what I usually do, returning the data. However, in this case it's not desired. We start jobs in `Script2` and manage the results connecting them to the correct object. Very complicated stuff... Returning the data is not an option I'm afraid :( It would've been a lot easier otherwise, that's true.

Comment: So now we don't know what problem you are trying to solve. Why is it necessary to use 2 scripts? Can you not convert Script2 to a function inside Script1? Or convert Script2 to a scriptblock inside Script1 and invoke it.

Comment: Because Script1 is very long and I tried to take make it easier to test by taking out some code related to executing jobs to another script.

Comment: That's a convenience problem rather than a technical one. One thing you can do is convert the code in `Script2` to a function. Dot source `Script2` and then call the function from `script1` as if it were a function defined in `script1`.

Comment: Agree, changed the approach entirely as this wasn't working. Thx anyhow for the help, I'll mark is as solved.